# ERROR : Base home directory does not exist within the container with Singularity container

Tags: singularity-container

I have built a sandbox singularity container on a server where I have full permissions:
`sudo singularity build --sandbox  myimage myrecipe`.

I moved it to another server.

When I run:

`singularity shell myimage`

I get access to the shell.

But, when I run:

`singularity shell -w  myimage`

I get:
`ERROR  : Base home directory does not exist within the container: /home`

What does this mean? Am I correct to assume this is because the `-w` is redundant, as sandbox images are already writable?

Answer (score 0):

when you call the option `shell`, you spawn an interactive shell within a container.
with `-w` option you need get  proper permissions to write to the container, then your do created the container with sudo, the $HOME in the writable directory myimage, you need use **sudo** for

`sudo singularity shell -w  myimage` and correctly bind on runtime the $HOME